# Sharepoint navigation changes orientation in configuration panel

Tags: 2013, branding

I have designed a vertical main menu for my sharepoint environment:

```
<!--SPM:<SharePoint:AspMenu 
ID="TopNavigationMenu" 
ShowStartingNode="false"
Runat="server" 
EnableViewState="false"
DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
AccessKey="&#60;%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%&#62;"
UseSimpleRendering="true"
UseSeparateCss="true"
Orientation="Vertical"
StaticDisplayLevels="4"
AdjustForShowStartingNode="false"
MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
SkipLinkText=""/>-->
```

It works fine until I go into the site settings. Than somehow the orientation changes from vertical back to horizontal.

Why does this happen? Do I need to hide the global menu inside the site-settings view?

**To clarify my question:** 
It's a SharePoint 2013 and the following pictures demonstrated how it looks (first) and how it should look (second).
[image: wrong horizontal orientation]

[image: right vertical orientation]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "/_layouts/15/settings.aspx" has a user control "~/_controltemplates/15/TopNavBar.ascx" included in top navigation and it will hard code a top navigation, override the one you have set in the master page. Like this:

```
<SharePoint:AspMenu
  ID="TopNavigationMenuV4"
  Runat="server"
  EnableViewState="false"
  DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
  AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,navigation_accesskey%>"
  UseSimpleRendering="true"
  UseSeparateCss="false"
  Orientation="Horizontal"
  StaticDisplayLevels="2"
  AdjustForShowStartingNode="true"
  MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="1"
  SkipLinkText=""
  CssClass="s4-tn" />
```

The only way to get around this, I think, is to use alternate header which is an aspx page that will render the header and the global navigation on all pages defined.

A blog post about Alternate headers here

http://sharingpoint.blogspot.se/2006/06/extreme-sharepoint-design-using.html

==== OR =====

you can take the global navigation away from it's content placeholder and hide the placeholder but then you will probably get some other navigation issues where the navigation source is not set properly.

//M

Comment: This works fine if I just change it in the file ~/_controltemplates/15/TopNavBar.ascx to vertical. Is this an acceptable way to change it, or will it bring up any other problems?

Comment: You should NEVER change an out of the box file. Then you can get issues when a service pack update will overwrite your changes. Then I think it's a better approach to remove the topbar from the contentplaceholder, hide that placeholder and then put it inside of your own placeholder. Then the topnavigation will look the same everywhere you use your master page BUT that may not be what you want.

Comment: thanks, it works by removing the contentplaceholder. My goal is to get the same Navigation on each page. Why should I not want this? Is there any problem with a global navigation?

Comment: The problem can be that you hide some navigation functionality that is out of the box, I haven't explored 2013 enough yet to tell you if this is a fact but some parts of SharePoint could be require access to that content placeholder

Comment: I heard there was a bounty for 50 on this one ;) anything else I can help you with? :)

Comment: I have to wait for 24 hours until I can give the bounty. In 40 minutes you will get your bounty ;)

Answer (score 1):

The Site Settings has another Master Page than the "normal" page.

Go to "Site Settings" => "Master Page". Then under System Master Page select the same as the Site Master Page.

Comment: sorry, this settings is just a list with all Master Pages (it's a 2013 sharepoint!). The rest of the settings pages all have the correct master-page style, only the main settings page not and there only the main navigation is orientated wrong...